# How do I return argument(s) as string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to make a function which can return argument(s) when it's called.

```
example( fooObject.foo[1] );
//return "fooObject.foo[1]"

example( fooFunc("foo",42) );
//return "fooFunc(\"foo\",42)"
```

like this.

I found out that I can get each arguments by using "arguments" method in the function, but cannot find the way to make the argument into the string.

Comment: your expected output?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I'm making some scripts for Adobe applications, And for there's no debuging tool supported in Aobe apps, I was trying to make one.

Comment: @BadDobby I haven't coded for an Adobe product for a while, but if I remember correct, there are ways to debug a code. I suggest you check [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/welcome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. A function is called with the *values* of its arguments, not the expressions that formed them. There is no way to access the code of the expressions as strings.

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking depends on how you define your function,
its very simply

```
function(a){return a}
```

whatever you passed in you will get out

Comment: You should read the question (and the already posted answers) more carefully. You're just returning the value of `a`. The OP is trying to return `"a"`.

Comment: NO..

    var fooObj = { foo: "bar" };
    function example(a){ ... };
    var result = example(fooObj.foo);
    
    I want to make the result like "fooObj.foo", not  "bar"

Comment: whats your use case?, if you want to have fooObj.foo, then pass it as string and use it wherever you want to use it